# How to remove duplicate items in recursive nested list

Tags: c#, list, linq, recursion

Here is a code sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
int counter = 0;
var services = new List<Service>
{
    new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "SG1", Services = new List<Service>
    {
        new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S1"},
        new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S2"},
        new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S3"},
        new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S4"},
        new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S5"},
        new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "SG2", 
        Services = new List<Service>
        {
            new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S3"},
            new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S4"},
            new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S5"},
            new Service {Id = ++counter,Code = "SG3", 
            Services = new List<Service>
            {
                new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S3"},
                new Service {Id = ++counter, Code = "S4"},
            }
        }
    }
}
}

}
};
```

The output I need to get out of this is the following:

- If a child list contains an item (same code) which exists in its parent, remove it from parent. Recursively work through every service until the final result is this:

`SG1    -->S1    -->S2    -->SG1    ------>S5    ------>SG3

---------->S3    ---------->S4`

Answer (score 3):

You do it with a depth-first traversal. You do not need LINQ for it.

Here is some pseudocode to give you an idea of how this could be done:

```
public static void RemoveDuplicates(Service service) {
    var toRemove = new HashSet<string>();
    RemoveDuplicates(service, toRemove);
}
private static void RemoveDuplicates(Service service, ISet<string> toRemove) {
    // Collect all child codes, and clean up children in the process
    foreach (var child in services) {
        RemoveDuplicates(child, toRemove);
    }
    // Remove all child codes from self
    foreach (var code in toRemove) {
        service.RemoveCode(code);
    }
    // Add the remaining codes for my parents to remove
    foreach (var myCode in allMyCodes) {
        toRemove.Add(myCode);
    }
}
```